# Getting a 400 error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a frustrating error in my macro code. I have a small bit of code in two subs one opens all data groups and changes some of the print options and the other closes the groups and changes some of the print options.

This works fine but when I save and close on re-open if I click the macro buttons I get a 400 error message. To fix this I have comment out all the .pagesetup code and then run the macros again then uncomment and run the macro line by line and then the 400 error will disappear. However once I save and close this will come back and I have to repeat everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub PropertyStrat_Click()
'
' PropertyStrat_Click Macro
'
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2 ' to expand the rows

Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA3
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Zoom = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.CenterVertically = True

End Sub

Sub SimpleView_Click()

ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1 ' to collapse the rows

Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$J$29,$A$30:$J$50"
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Zoom = 100
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.CenterVertically = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a 1004 error on the papersize line. Here are the available options for that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834612.aspx

Comment: I don't know why the error is there.  Perhaps my printer doesn't support xlPaperA3 because it appears to be a viable option.

Comment: which line does error out?

Comment: When you get to the bottom of the issue Adam, check out `With` and `End With` for a tidy up.

Comment: which sheet is `ActiveSheet` ?